# preg_replace - similar patterns

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a string that contains something like "LAB_FF, LAB_FF12" and I'm trying to use preg_replace to look for both patterns and replace them with different strings using a pattern match of;

```
/LAB_[0-9A-F]{2}|LAB_[0-9A-F]{4}/
```

So input would be

```
LAB_FF, LAB_FF12
```

and the output would need to be

```
DAB_FF, HAD_FF12
```

Problem is, for the second string, it interprets it as "LAB_FF" instead of "LAB_FF12" and so the output is

```
DAB_FF, DAB_FF
```

I've tried splitting the input line out using 2 different preg_match statements, the first looking for the {2} pattern and the second looking for the {4} pattern. This sort of works in that I can get the correct output into 2 separate strings but then can't combine the two strings to give the single amended output.

Comment: Show the code you used for replacing things.

Comment: Anything wrong with the answers posted here? Please tell me if something is wrong so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` is word boundary. Meaning it will look at where the word ends and not only pattern match.

https://regex101.com/r/upY0gn/1

```
$pattern = "/\bLAB_[0-9A-F]{2}\b|\bLAB_[0-9A-F]{4}\b/";
```

---

Seeing the comment on the other answer about how to replace the string.
This is one way.

The pattern will create empty entries in the output array for each pattern that fails.
In this case one (the first).
Then it's just a matter of substr.

```
$re = '/(\bLAB_[0-9A-F]{2}\b)|(\bLAB_[0-9A-F]{4}\b)/';
$str = 'LAB_FF12';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

$substitutes = ["", "DAB", "HAD"];

For($i=1; $i<count($matches); $i++){
    If($matches[$i] != ""){
         $result = $substitutes[$i] . substr($matches[$i],3);
         Break;
    }
}

Echo $result;
```

https://3v4l.org/gRvHv

Answer (score 0):

You can specify exact amounts in one set of curly braces, e.g. `{2,4}.

Just tested this and seems to work:

```
/LAB_[0-9A-F]{2,4}/
LAB_FF, LAB_FFF, LAB_FFFF
```

EDIT: My mistake, that actually matches between 2 and 4. If you change the order of your selections it matches the first it comes to, e.g.

```
/LAB_([0-9A-F]{4}|[0-9A-F]{2})/
LAB_FF, LAB_FFFF
```

EDIT2: The following will match `LAB_even_amount_of_characters`:

```
/LAB_([0-9A-F]{2})+/
LAB_FF, LAB_FFFF, LAB_FFFFFF...
```

Comment: Cheers, that seems to work. Any ideas how I can perform a preg_replace so that "LAB_FF" would get replaced with "X" and "LAB_FFFF" would get replaced with "Y" ?